# How to get the sql print message using pymssql

Tags: python-3.4, pymssql, console-output

I'm running some queries, that print runtime stats from their execution.

It's done through 
    `print('message')`
used within the sql script.

I would want to see these messages while calling the procedures/scripts through pymssql.

```
conn = pymssql.connect(server, user, password, "tempdb")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("print('message')")
conn.commit()
```

Above script doesn't return anything, and I can't find any tips on how to get that print to show up in the console output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution that let's me still use pymssql and get the print messages.
`pymssql.Connection` actually uses `_mssql.MSSQLConnection` internally.
This means that you can use [this](http://pymssql.org/en/stable/_mssql_examples.html#custom-message-handlers) example by accessing that internal object.

```
connection = pymssql.connect(server='server_address', database='db_name')
connection._conn.set_msghandler(my_msg_handler)  # Install our custom handler
```

where the my_msg_handler is the same type of object as in [pmssql wiki](http://pymssql.org/en/stable/_mssql_examples.html#custom-message-handlers).
Accessing internal objects is not ideal, but it's the only way I've found if you don't want to use a different library and need to get the SQL prints.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way, but you can refactor your SQL. For example:

```
DECLARE @my_var AS VARCHAR(200)
PRINT 'Setting a variable...'
SET @my_var = 'this'
PRINT 'I am some output'
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE this = @my_var
```

Could be refactored to be something like this:

```
DECLARE @my_var AS VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @messages AS VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @messages = @messages + 'Setting a variable...'
SET @my_var = 'this'
SET @messages = @messages + 'I am some output'
SELECT @messages, * FROM my_table WHERE this = @my_var
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, good idea. 

Sadly, this is to support a CI solution for a database with over 6000 scripts, so .... I'm not convincing anyone to refactor all that :)

While trying to make this work I had learned that _mssql, which is part of the pymssql package, is actually able to return the messages, but in this case I have issues with integrated login use.

I'll post some info if I find a solution.

Answer (score -1):

In order to print something into the console in pymssql, you don't need to put the print inside the execute function. you can simply use

```
print("message")
```

so your code will be

```
conn = pymssql.connect(server, user, password, "tempdb")
cursor = conn.cursor()
print("message")
conn.commit()
```

Comment: Let me rephrase, I have an existing process in SQL that has prints, and I need to see those in console output.

Comment: @Shammas The question is about seeing the output of print statements that are inside SQL stored procedures, for example