# How to retrieve the exact response of insert/update statement of Query Explorer SQL Server through python using pymssql

Tags: sql, sql-server, python-3.x, pymssql

Insert/Update statements always provide updated rows and inserted columns in SQL Server Query Explorer Response Window.

Want to retrieve the same results from **Python 3.x.**

I have millions of records and need to know every update count and insert count like we get response in SQL Server

Already tried **cursor.lastrowid** But always provide LAST Id which is updated.

```
#Sample code to provide connection strings
import pymssql
server = 'myserver'
username = 'myusername'
password = 'password'
connection_obj = pymssql.connect(host=server,user=username,password=password,database='mydb')
cursor = connection_obj.cursor()
cursor.execute("Insert into mydb(Id, name) values(44, 'SOMETHING')")
connection_obj.commit()
```

Expected Output (As displayed on SQL Query Response Window)

If Inserted/Updated :

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

....

Comment: My GoogleFu is telling me that Python does not support reading of the `PRINT` statements from SQL server.

Comment: @Larnu Can we have any function or anythin that returns the string or response back from SQL? Just need the response from SQL

Comment: @Larnu - How about  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47887285/2144390)?

Comment: Looks like it, @GordThompson . As I said, it was my GoogleFu telling me that; doesn't mean it doesn't. Of course, I somehow doubt the OP really wants `(1 row(s) affected)`, they probably just want the `1` that David has guessed.

Answer (score 0):

If your driver doesn't provide the row count messages, you can return the row counts with a query that returns the value of the [@@rowcount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) system function.  eg

```
cursor.execute("Insert into mydb(Id, name) values(44, 'SOMETHING'); select @@rowcount rc;")
row = cursor.fetchone() 
rowCount = row[0]
```

Comment: For Insert it worked like a charm ! 

Can you help me with updated rows as well ?
Query will be like : 
cursor.execute("Insert into mydb(Id, name) values(44, 'SOMETHING'); Update table set mycolumn = 'value'; ")
Both the statements into one !!

Comment: You can't perform an `UPDATE` and `INSERT` in the same statement, @ojasmehta. you'll have to capture the value of `@@rowcount` after each DML statement and add it to an "aggregating variable".